# Python Basemap Heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, matplotlib-basemap, colorbar

I am trying to copy the method that was done on this page: https://makersportal.com/blog/2018/7/20/geographic-mapping-from-a-csv-file-using-python-and-basemap under "Mapping Interesting Data" to have a color bar associated with my data.

Right now I just get a plain map of South America, which is what I want as my background but there is no data included.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='mill',
            llcrnrlat = -30, #bottom
            llcrnrlon = -120, #left 
            urcrnrlat = 20, #top
            urcrnrlon = -50, #right 
            resolution='c')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()

# format colors for elevation range
SST_min = np.min(df5.DaasgardSST)
SST_max = np.max(df5.DaasgardSST)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('gist_earth')
normalize = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=SST_min, vmax=SST_max)

# plot SST with different colors
for i in range(0,len(df5.DaasgardSST)):
    x,y = m(lon,lat)
    color_interp = np.interp(df5,[SST_min,SST_max],[0,30])
    plt.plot(x,y,marker='o',markersize=6,color=cmap(int(color_interp)))

# format the colorbar 
cax, _ = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(ax)
cbar = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap,norm=normalize,label='Elevation')


plt.title('Title')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `m.plot()` in stead of `plt.plot()`.

Comment: If you are getting the map but no data, then have you made sure you have the correct format for the lat/lon formatting? Can't see your data.